# Drop down select list for custom Magento system configuration section

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

I need to select one value from multiple options using a drop down select list in a custom system config file.

How should I write the config file?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this code.

**system.xml**

```
<field id="list_mode" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>List Mode</label>        
   <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListMode</source_model>
</field>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListMode.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class ListMode implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
 public function toOptionArray()
 {
  return [
    ['value' => 'grid', 'label' => __('Grid Only')],
    ['value' => 'list', 'label' => __('List Only')],
    ['value' => 'grid-list', 'label' => __('Grid (default) / List')],
    ['value' => 'list-grid', 'label' => __('List (default) / Grid')]
  ];
 }
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: Fatal error: Cannot declare class SpedizioniList, because the name is already in use in ....

Comment: @Giuseppe ask a question and write your code.

Comment: there is no need to ask a duplicate question ;),  for M2 v.2.1.1 your code works perfectly by adding the namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source; before the class declaration. Hope may helps other developer. thank you

Comment: @Giuseppe Great.

Comment: I'm facing following error: Element 'source_model': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source
                        \Shippingmethods' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Za-z0-9_\\:]+'.

Answer (score 7):

As Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface has been deprecated since v.102.0.1, I'm posting it in the current standard adopted by Magento (I'm using 2.3.3 and PHP 7.3):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

/**
 * Class Profile
 * @package Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Source
 */
class Profile implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray() : array
    {
        return [
            ['value' => '', 'label' => __('-- Select an Option --')],
            ['value' => 'grid', 'label' => __('Grid Only')],
            ['value' => 'list', 'label' => __('List Only')],
            ['value' => 'grid-list', 'label' => __('Grid (default) / List')],
            ['value' => 'list-grid', 'label' => __('List (default) / Grid')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use these files:

**system.xml**

```
<field id="select" translate="label" type="select"
       sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Select Option</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Products</source_model>
</field>
```

**Model file**

```
Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Products implements ArrayInterface
{
    /*
     * Option getter
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    /*
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $choose = [
            '1' => 'A',
            '2' => 'B',
            '3' => 'C',
            '4' => 'D'
            
        ];
        return $choose;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

\Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface is  deprecated instead we can use 
\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface

Comment: on please let me know on which version this class is deprecated?

Comment: Hi @renu did u worked in kensium?